# Vaadin v24, Tabs autoselect not loading the view

Tags: tabs, vaadin

I am facing some issues with Tabs and would like to know if I am doing something wrong please:

What I have:
`MainView` extends `AppLayout`
I am using the `NavBar` in `Mainview` with some Tabs.
All Tabs are own TabViews. (`View1.class` and `View2.class`)
Each TabViews has
`@Route(value = "View1", layout = MainView.class)`
and
`@Route(value = "View2", layout = MainView.class)`

The Mainview starts and I can see the tabs.
If I press the tab, then the content of each TabView is shown.

But after loading, the MainView (after loading the Mainview first time), I can see the first TAB is selected but the View1.class is not shown.
If I press the first Tab now, then view1 is loading.

```java
Tabs tabs = new Tabs(true);
tabs.add(createTab("View1", View1.class));
tabs.add(createTab("View2", View2.class));
```

```java
private Tab createTab(String viewName, Class <? extends Component> view) {
    RouterLink link = new RouterLink(view);
    link.add(viewName);
    link.setTabIndex(-1);
    return new Tab(link);
}
```

Do I have to call something somewhere to not just select the TAB but also trigger to load the view?

Reading the documentation which explains AutoSelect but does not explain how to trigger page load.

Comment: Please take a look at https://cookbook.vaadin.com/tabs-with-routes/a if you really want this structure. Even tho the whole tab thing is not needed. Just add Routerlinks to create links for the differentviews.

Comment: Thank you @Knoobie. But I am not really sure how this resolves the problem.
In your example, RouteTabs extends Tabs so tabs are used as well.
I also tried to use the beforeEnterObserver to set the TAB, but selecting seems not to be the problem.
Even if I select the second TAB, I can see its selected. But the view is not shown.
The problem does not seems to be the selection itself, its the "showing" part of the selected TAB.

Comment: If you open the app, an empty route / default is loaded. Therefore your "view1" is not shown. Clicking the link inside the tab shows obviously "view1". Your code can't work like this. You are just adding links to an instance of tabs and auto select of nothing (content of the tab) is nothing. Clicking the tabs, does not trigger the tabs but the links you have added to the tabs.

Comment: @Knoobie
Now I understood. 

the following is required in beforeEnter to load the view.
            event.forwardTo(View1.class);
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please add your solution as the answer? Thank you